# Unable to create web page from content type in custom pages library in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, library

I have a requirement to create a custom ***Web Pages Library*** using `CSOM` code.

I am able to create a library and apply the custom content type but when I try creating a page, it gives an error.

Please help.

Comment: Post here your code

Comment: what is the error its giving?

Comment: What kind of error?